# An internal table is not allowed as a workarea error

Tags: select, abap, opensql

When reading data into an internal table using the Select command, I get the error:

> An internal table is not allowed as a workarea

I do not understand the cause. I have attached the ABAP source code. What am I doing wrong?
the error happens at the following position:  `SELECT SINGLE * FROM (lv_infotype-infotype) INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF lt_itab`

```
infotypes: 0007, 0008, 0009, 0010, 0013, 0014, 0015, 0016, 0699. 

tables: pernr, pa0007, pa0008, pa0009, pa0010, pa0013, pa0014, pa0015, pa0016, pa0699.
      
types: BEGIN OF ty_itab,
        pernr       type pernr-mstbr, "Personalnummer
        infotype(6) type c,
        begda       type p0008-begda,
        endda       type p0008-endda,
        UNAME       type p0008-uname,
      END OF ty_itab.
      
Data: lt_itab TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_itab.       

TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_infotypes,
         infotype(6) TYPE c,
       END OF ty_infotypes.

DATA: c_infotypes TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_infotypes INITIAL SIZE 0,
      lv_infotype  TYPE ty_infotypes.

APPEND VALUE #( infotype = 'PA0007' ) TO c_infotypes.
APPEND VALUE #( infotype = 'PA0008' ) TO c_infotypes.
APPEND VALUE #( infotype = 'PA0009' ) TO c_infotypes.
APPEND VALUE #( infotype = 'PA0010' ) TO c_infotypes.
APPEND VALUE #( infotype = 'PA0013' ) TO c_infotypes.
APPEND VALUE #( infotype = 'PA0014' ) TO c_infotypes.
APPEND VALUE #( infotype = 'PA0015' ) TO c_infotypes.
APPEND VALUE #( infotype = 'PA0016' ) TO c_infotypes.
APPEND VALUE #( infotype = 'PA0699' ) TO c_infotypes.

GET pernr.

LOOP AT c_infotypes INTO lv_infotype.
   SELECT SINGLE * FROM (lv_infotype-infotype) INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF lt_itab <=ERROR!
    WHERE sprps = 'X' AND pernr = pernr-pernr.
  IF sy-subrc = 0.
    WRITE: / pernr-pernr, lv_infotype-infotype.
  ENDIF.
ENDLOOP.

...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `SELECT SINGLE *` only returns a single row. What the syntax check is trying to tell you is that you don't need a whole table to store the result. You only need a structure. If you want the result in a table with one line for some reason, don't use `SELECT SINGLE *`. Use a regular `SELECT *`. And if you want to make sure you never get more than one line, you can use the addition `UP TO 1 ROWS`.

However, in this particular example it appears that you want the data for all the different infotypes in one internal table. You don't want your `SELECT` to overwrite the results of the previous loop iteration, you want it to append the result to those you already have. In that case you should not use `INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE` but `APPENDING CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE`. This mode works just fine with `SELECT SINGLE` and allows you to use it with an internal table instead of a structure (because appending to a structure would make even less sense).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I changed it to `appending CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF table itab` and it works fine. I am always struggling with the decision to define an internal table or a structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to implement a SELECT from an internal table you need to use @ and also using alias in your FROM instruction.

SELECT SINGLE * FROM @c_infotypes AS itab INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF @lt_itab.

In this case by the way you can use a simple READ.

Be careful because in the example above you are trying to extract from a flat variable --> lv_infotype-infotype

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the question. The author doesn't want to read rows from the internal table `c_infotypes`. That internal table has the names of database tables in the field `infotype`. They want to dynamically select data from those database tables.